# When i Automate the Gmail login module in web driver it display below error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My code is

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://gmail.com");

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Email']"));
    element.sendKeys("asangal90@gmail.com");

    element = driver.findElement(By.name("signIn"));
    element.click();

    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Passwd']"));
    element.sendKeys("123456");

    element = driver.findElement(By.name("signIn"));
    element.click();

        }
```

And the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='Passwd']"}
Command duration or timeout: 64 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'CoolAkku-PC', ip: '10.209.176.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='Passwd']}
Session ID: 72a7bd1d-e9e9-4ac7-8c1c-c91c1717990d
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=37.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at myclass.main(myclass.java:22)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='Passwd']"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:03:33'
System info: host: 'CoolAkku-PC', ip: '10.209.176.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/COOLAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous207772722037832049webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10723)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement(file:///C:/Users/COOLAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous207772722037832049webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10732)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/COOLAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous207772722037832049webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/COOLAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous207772722037832049webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12619)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/COOLAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous207772722037832049webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the driver doesn't wait for the elements to exist in the DOM. Define implicit wait to tell the driver to wait some time before throwing an exception

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will tell the driver to search for the elements up to 5 seconds.